OpenCV merge() failing: (-215:Assertion failed) mv[i].size == mv[0].size && mv[i].depth() == depth in function 'merge'
My code throws this error when I call cv.merge():
(-215:Assertion failed) mv[i].size == mv[0].size && mv[i].depth() == depth in function 'merge'
I don't know why it is happening. Can anyone give a suggestion?
# Convert RGB to CIELAB color space
image_lab = cv2.cvtColor(input_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)

# Split the input image into individual color channels (BGR order)
b, g, r = cv2.split(input_image)

# Calculate the mean value of each color channel
mean_r = np.mean(r)
mean_g = np.mean(g)
mean_b = np.mean(b)

# Calculate the mean value of the gray image
mean_gray = np.mean(input_image)

# Calculate the individual value for each channel
r_corrected = r - 0.3 * (mean_gray - mean_r) * g * (1 - r)
b_corrected = b + 0.3 * (mean_gray - mean_b) * g * (1 - b)

# Ensure that all channels have the same mean value
mean_r_corrected = np.mean(r_corrected)
mean_b_corrected = np.mean(b_corrected)
mean_correction = (mean_r_corrected + mean_b_corrected) / 2

# Apply color correction to make all channels have the same mean value
r_corrected = r_corrected + mean_correction - mean_r_corrected
b_corrected = b_corrected + mean_correction - mean_b_corrected

# Check channel shapes and data types
print("Shape of b_corrected:", b_corrected.shape)
print("Shape of g:", g.shape)
print("Shape of r_corrected:", r_corrected.shape)

print("Data type of b_corrected:", b_corrected.dtype)
print("Data type of g:", g.dtype)
print("Data type of r_corrected:", r_corrected.dtype)

# Merge the corrected channels with the original green channel
corrected_image = cv2.merge([b_corrected, g, r_corrected])

# Display the corrected image
cv2.imshow('Corrected Image', corrected_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

Drive already mounted at /content/drive; to attempt to forcibly remount, call drive.mount("/content/drive", force_remount=True).
Shape of b_corrected: (313, 373)
Shape of g: (313, 373)
Shape of r_corrected: (313, 373)
Data type of b_corrected: float64
Data type of g: uint8
Data type of r_corrected: float64
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-9def3a429c8c> in <cell line: 13>()
     51 
     52     # Merge the corrected channels with the original green channel
---> 53     corrected_image = cv2.merge([b_corrected, g, r_corrected])
     54 
     55     # Display the corrected image

error: OpenCV(4.8.0) /io/opencv/modules/core/src/merge.dispatch.cpp:129: error: (-215:Assertion failed) mv[i].size == mv[0].size && mv[i].depth() == depth in function 'merge'


All 3 components need to have the same data type as well. You are trying to merge float64 and uint8 together, that can't work.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
